# What does the Join button in the categorized style tab do?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm just studing gis, and I use QGIS. I have found in the layer properties some JOIN and don't understand how can I use It?

Maybe someone can help me to understand it.

[image]

Comment: Its a bug, never work. Dont have any use right now
I ask about it in a qgis Developpers chat